# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer does not react on Subview

Tags: ios, xamarin

Im trying to implement a Slidemenu, which takes place on the left side of the mainview. With adding an `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` on the left side I do the Slide-In-Part. This works really great but now of course I also should be able to slide it out. So I thought I just could do the same thing from the mainview but now on the right side of the slidemenu. But now Ive got the problem that it doesnt respond at all.

**The SlideMenu is a `subview` from the mainview and when it's slided out, it covers 3/4 of the screen.**

```
FavoritenMenu = new SlideMenu("Left");
AddSubview(FavoritenMenu);

//SlideRecognizers
SideMenuSlideRecognizerLeft.Edges = UIRectEdge.Left;
SideMenuSlideRecognizerLeft.AddTarget(() => { HandleSlideLeft(); });
AddGestureRecognizer(SideMenuSlideRecognizerLeft);
```

**Declaring the SlideRecognizer in the SlideMenu:**

```
SlideEdgeRecognizer.Edges = UIRectEdge.Right;

SlideEdgeRecognizer.AddTarget(() => { HandleSlide(); });
AddGestureRecognizer(SlideEdgeRecognizer);
```

I placed a breakpoint in the method `HandleSlide()` to see when it enters, but actually it never enters. So I replaced it with a normal `GestureRecognizer` and what a surprise it entered the method.

So has anyone an idea if this is a bug or if I missed something? Thanks for any respond.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two gesture recognizers. You can see how I fixed it/implemented it in FlyoutNavigation:
https://github.com/Clancey/FlyoutNavigation/commit/3471c0d9ff7dfd86db460391fdd64c73da0bd512